# A simple Lua interpreter embedded in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, lua, wxwidgets

I am trying to write a simple Lua interpreter using wxWidgets as my GUI. I am reading the Lua command from a multiline textbox. Here is my code:

```
    wxString cmdStr = m_OutputWindow->GetLineText(line-1); //Read text

    const char* commandStr=(const char*)cmdStr.mb_str();
    int err=luaL_loadbuffer(luastate,commandStr,strlen(commandStr),"line")||lua_pcall(luastate, 0, 0, 0);
    wxString outputstr;
    if(err)
    {
        outputstr=wxString::FromUTF8(lua_tostring(luastate,-1));
        lua_pop(luastate, 1);
    }
```

If I try to evaluate a simple expression like 3+5 then I get the following error

```
 [string "line"]:1: syntax error near <eof>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: `3+5` isn't a valid Lua statement, it's an expression. Try something like `print(3+5)` instead. http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExpressionsAsStatements

Comment: If I give the command: print(3+5) then I get the following error
[string "line"]:1: unexpected symbol near char(236)

Comment: @macroland. I suggest you try putting the command as a const string. That will take wxWidgets out of the equation for the moment. `const char* commandStr="return 3+5";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to enter an expression (like `1+2` or `a+math.sqrt(b)`), you must prepend "return " to it before giving it to the interpreter:

```
const std::string cmdStr = "return " + m_OutputWindow->GetLineText(line-1).ToStdString();
int err = luaL_loadbuffer(luastate, cmdStr.c_str() , cmdStr.size(), "line") 
       || lua_pcall(luastate, 0, 0, 0);
```

However, you probably don't want to prepend it if the user enter a statement (like `a=1; b=2`). Since you are reading multiline text code you are likely getting string of statements separated by newlines. In this case you should not prepend return; the issue with your test is that you were executing an expression, can't be done. Test with statement(s), several comments show some like the following are all statements

```
a=4
return 1+2
return math.sqrt(a)
print('hi')
```

whereas

```
a
4
1+2
math.sqrt(a)
'hi'
```

are all expressions. Note that lua_tostring will return whatever the chunk returns. If the chunk doesn't return anything then lua_tostring will return nil, just as any function that returns nothing would do when called as `ret=func(whatever)`.

Comment: Or add it automatically if compilation fails.

Comment: @lhf good idea; I guess it's probably a good idea to distinguish between expression and statement

Comment: Sorry I keep deleting my comments. It seems that lua_tostring(luastate,-1) keeps returning LUA_TNIL. However, if I redirect to stdout I can see for example the result of `print(3)`.

Comment: @macroland I've extended my answer hth